# nginx: automatically listen on IPv6 if enabled

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure nginx so that it listens on IPV6 if ipv6 is enabled on the machine. I added the following line to nginx conf file.

```
listen [::]:443 ipv6only=off;
```

But this fails with following error

```
nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:443 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the nginx should listen on whichever ip family is enabled.